# How to use a remote desktop app to extend display from Windows to iPad?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, ipad, extended-desktop

I have an iPad Pro, and I am looking to use it as a second monitor for my work computer which is Windows. Since this is a work computer, I am unable to download any third-party applications/drivers to it (Splashtop, Spacedesk, Duet, etc). However, I do have Remote Desktop already installed and can connect to my computer from my iPad using the Remote Desktop Client app on the iPad.

When I connect to my computer from my iPad using Remote Desktop Client, the screen on my computer locks.

I was wondering if there was a way to use Remote Desktop to not mirror the display, but rather extend the display from my computer to my iPad?

Comment: What you are attempting to do is an extreme corner case, which cannot be accomplished, with additional software. I am not even saying it is possible even with additional software.